# Not progressively measurable process example - proof.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to understand example of process which is adapted and measurable but not progressively measure.

I am analyzing Example 0.3 from this paper:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-communications-in-probability/volume-18/issue-none/On-existence-of-progressively-measurable-modifications/10.1214/ECP.v18-2548.full

[image]

And the question is: why  $\mathbb{1}_{\Delta}$ is a pointwise limit of functions of the form  $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} c_{k} \mathbb{1}_{B_{k} \times C_{k}}$$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $c_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$, $B_{k} \in \mathcal{B}([0, \frac{1}{2}])$, $C_{k} \in \mathcal{A}$???

I completely don't see it...

Comment: Isn't any measurable function the pointwise limit of simple functions ?

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, thank you. But why $B_{k}$, $C_{k}$ looks like that? Is that indicator $\mathbb{1}_{B_{k} \times C_{k}} (t, \omega)$ or we have $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{B_{k} \times C_{k}} (\omega)$ ?

Comment: Ok, I think it has to be $\mathbb{1}_{\Delta} (s, \omega)$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} c_{k} \mathbb{1}_{B_{k} \times C_{k}} (s, \omega)$$ for $s \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, but I don't feel this $B_{k}$, $C_{k}$ sequences. Not enough analysis probably :P

Comment: @TheBridge: Limit of simple functions over the product $\sigma$-field. That is, limit of things of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \Bbb 1_{E_k}(s,\omega)$, where the $E_k$ are in $\mathscr B([0,1/2])\otimes\mathscr F_{1/2}$. But the assertion made is considerably stronger, it seems.

Comment: Ok, so $\mathbb{1}_{\Delta}$ is limit of simple functions over the product $\sigma$-field as a measurable function... But what is about $D_{k}$ and later $\mathcal{D}$? I am confused about the idea